# How to integrate .NET web application project (API) with Apache Cordova Project?

Tags: asp.net, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

So this is the issue:

I have a .NET project that includes 5 Web Application Layers.
One of them is API.

I Recently added a Cordova project as well and I'd like it to communicate with the API Layer.

Is there anyone who knows what to do?

P.S.:

I use visual studio 2013.

Comment: cordova index.html use JavaScript ajax post call webapi with Cors enable

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal jQuery Ajax calls to make requests to the API.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or just normal JavaScript ajax https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567149/487940.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about calling into Web API web services from a Cordova app, you may find the [Breeze.JS](http://www.getbreezenow.com/breezejs) framework useful to help you. You can either just used the client library or use some server side code in addition to client code to help get you up and running and exposing new web services as well.

Otherwise it is simply a matter of making web service calls to the server from your JavaScript code but the specifics will depend on exactly what you're trying to do and what client UI/utility framework you are using.